# perform massively parallelizable tasks in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I often find myself performing massively parallelizable tasks in spark, but for some reason, spark keeps on dying. For instance, right now I have two tables (both stored on s3) that are essentially just collections of (unique) strings. I want to cross join, compute levenshtein distance, and write it out to s3 as a new table. So my code looks like:

```py
OUT_LOC = 's3://<BUCKET>/<PREFIX>/'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('my-app') \
        .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class",
                "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
    tb0 = spark.sql('SELECT col0 FROM db0.table0')
    tb1 = spark.sql('SELECT col1 FROM db1.table1')

    spark.sql("set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true")

    tb0.join(tb1).withColumn("levenshtein_distance",
                             F.levenshtein(F.col("col0"), F.col("col1"))) \
        .write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite') \
        .options(path=OUT_LOC, compression='snappy', maxRecordsPerFile=10000) \
        .saveAsTable('db2.new_table')
```

It seems to me that this is massively parallelizable, and spark should be able to chug through this while only reading in a minimal amount of data at a time. But for some reason, the tasks keep on ghost dying.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a setting I'm missing? Or just more generally, what's going on here?
2. There's no reason for the whole thing to be stored locally, right?
3. What are some best practices here that I should consider?

For what it's worth, I have googled around extensively, but couldn't find anyone else with this issue. Maybe my google-foo isn't strong enough, or maybe I'm just doing something stupid.

### edit

To @egordoe's advice...
I ran the `explain` and got back the following...

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [col0#0, col1#3, levenshtein('col0, 'col1) AS levenshtein_distance#14]
+- Join Inner
   :- Project [col0#0]
   :  +- Project [col0#0]
   :     +- SubqueryAlias `db0`.`table0`
   :        +- Relation[col0#0] parquet
   +- Project [col1#3]
      +- Project [col1#3]
         +- SubqueryAlias `db1`.`table1`
            +- Relation[col1#3] parquet

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
col0: string, col1: string, levenshtein_distance: int
Project [col0#0, col1#3, levenshtein(col0#0, col1#3) AS levenshtein_distance#14]
+- Join Inner
   :- Project [col0#0]
   :  +- Project [col0#0]
   :     +- SubqueryAlias `db0`.`table0`
   :        +- Relation[col0#0] parquet
   +- Project [col1#3]
      +- Project [col1#3]
         +- SubqueryAlias `db1`.`table1`
            +- Relation[col1#3] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [col0#0, col1#3, levenshtein(col0#0, col1#3) AS levenshtein_distance#14]
+- Join Inner
   :- Relation[col0#0] parquet
   +- Relation[col1#3] parquet

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=false)
+- Project [col0#0, col1#3, levenshtein(col0#0, col1#3) AS levenshtein_distance#14]
   +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Inner
      :- FileScan parquet db0.table0[col0#0] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://REDACTED], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<col0:string>
      +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
         +- FileScan parquet db1.table1[col1#3] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://REDACTED], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<col1:string>
========== finished
```

Seems reasonable to me, but the explanation doesn't include the actual writing of the data. I assume that's because it likes to build up a cache of results locally then ship the whole thing to s3 as a table after? That would be pretty lame.

### edit 1

I also ran the `foreach` example you suggested with a simple `print` statement in there. It hung around for 40 minutes without printing anything before I killed it. I'm now running the job with a function that does nothing (it's just a `pass` statement) to see if it even finishes.

Comment: have you monitored your job in the spark ui? how many records is it processing per task? do you get any logs/traceback?

Comment: I don't get any tracebacks, but I get plenty of logs. It reads a bunch of files, and (presumably) cross joins them correctly. I can get it to start dumping out files to s3, but it ghost fails. Then `yarn logs --applicationId APP_ID` no longer loads the logs.

Comment: how may records per source?

Comment: you mean like how many records are in each of the two input tables? Somewhere in the high (maybe hundreds of) thousands.

Comment: Not enough information is given to tell anything definite. On the cross join, this type of join is pretty slow but is pretty stable at the same time. There are very few situations that may cause OOMs. OOMs may happen though. The cross join caches first `spark.sql.cartesianProductExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold` rows directly in the heap (not in the memory Spark reserved for its purposes). So, it means an OOM may be thrown if the average row size of your dataset is pretty big or you have configured too many cores per executor.

Comment: To ensure that this caching implementation is not an issue, you can re-run your job with some low `spark.sql.cartesianProductExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold`. For example, 100.
On top of that, I would suggest isolating the problem. To make sure that the problem is in the join, just replace `.write...` with `foreach()` with some dummy code inside. This will ensure that the problem is not in that writing part that you do an the end.

Comment: And the last thing, I would also propose to print the execution plan of your code. It will rule out obvious errors that are not always visible just by looking at the code. `tb0.join(tb1).explain(true)` will do the trick.

Comment: wow I left for lunch and came back to a plan of action! I love it! Thanks @egordoe!
So what is a good source to understand which things use which memory allocations? I've noticed there are a whole slew of different memory configurations available.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I don't know any good consistent source besides the Spark code. But the good thing is that the code itself has a bunch of comments, and, therefore, you can read it even not being fluent in Scala. The caching I talked about is implemented in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray.scala
This class is used in multiple places in Spark, including in SortMergeJoin and CartesianProduct implementations. So, having just a rough idea of how does it work may sometimes help in debugging.

Comment: Aha! The physical plan shed some light on it. Spark does the joining using `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin` instead of slower `CartesianProductJoin`. It means Spark believes that the `db1.table1` is small enough to fit the memory! But this assumption might be wrong. `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` property controls when Broadcast is used. This optimization can be disabled by setting the threshold to -1.

Comment: And you might aslo want to consider doing `ANALYZE TABLE <tableName> COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan` for your tables as suggested in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options

Comment: So this is something akin to when a database stores stats on tables to inform the query planner? Will the `Analyze table` command store those stats somewhere so they can be used next time?